# Lombok is woking in commad line but it is not in "Run Java Application"(Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, lombok

I am using Lombok(1.18.12) and Eclipse-2020-03-(4.15.0). I am already the intallation  of Lombok, to JAR. I already see in file "eclipse.ini" the your configuration. But It is not working when I execute the program(Spring boot + Maven) for Eclipse(Run Application), but when I execute the program for command line It work.

Why?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Eclipse is loading lombok, you can do that by opening the About Eclipse dialog, you should see  **Lombok v1.18.12 "Envious Ferret" is installed.** If you don't see that, then lombok is not running. On my machine I have that problem when I start eclipse with `./eclipse` instead of using `Eclipse.app` wich loads lombok just fine.